# Filtering by ID column

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010

I am trying to filter a table from Ms access DB in visual studio by ID (PID) column but I can't figure out how to convert int to string, or to make it work.

Any ideas please.

```
    con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource
    con.Open()

    If PIDfindTextBox.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a Patient ID number")
    Else
        PatienrocordBindingSource.Filter = "((PID,'system.string') like '" & PIDfindTextBox.Text & "')"
        If PatienrocordBindingSource.Count <> 0 Then
            With dataGridView1.DataSource = PatienrocordBindingSource
            End With
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Searched Patient ID was not found")
            PatienrocordBindingSource.Filter = Nothing
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is very confused. It opens a database connection then sets a bindingsource filter, this isn't really how things go

A bindingsource is a device that sits between a model of data such as a datatable (which is not a table in a database) and a UI element such as a datagridview or other controls. The bindingsource can filter the data it finds in the model. None of this is anything to do with filling the model up with data in the first place, which often is done by pulling it out of a database

You can probably avoid interacting with a database connection entirely; if you use an OledbDataAdapter you can pull data out of your database and load it into a datatable in your program's memory

You thus have a choice of where to filter your data. You either load the entire database into your program's memory and then use bindingsource filter to show just the one if you want - all the data lives in the datatable and only some of it passes through the bindingsource ..

Or you only download some of the data out of the database and into the datatable, and then you don't need to filter it in the bindingsource

You can also take a hybrid approach of loading, say, 10 records into the datatable and then filtering In the bindingsource

---

Choose your scenario - most people opt for the middle one where you just download the data you need. There are plenty of examples out there but as a rough template, searching a database table by I'd and pulling the results would look like:

```
Dim da as New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Id =?", "connection string here")
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", Convert.ToInt32(idTextbox.Text))
Dim dt as New DataTable
da.Fill(dt)
bindingsource.DataSource = dt
```

If you had 10 rows in your datatable and wanted to filter to just some one id

```
bindingsource.Filter = "[Id] = " & idFilterTextBox.Text
```

You don't need to use both of these approaches; use the one that is right for your context

Comment: thank you for your reply 
I am just so new to programming so I know I might sound silly with my previous question
I think Oi have asked the question in a wrong way maybe 
so have 2 forms, 1 form where the data has been inserted to a table i a database 
then I have this form where I want to search the previous table to display only one record(row) for one ID number which I enter in a text box
so I am trying to create a search button for that 
But the main issue is that my PID column is int and bindingsource,fillter uses string
again thank you very much for your help and answer

Comment: I managed to do so with text change event  
`con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource
        con.Open()

        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        ds.Tables.Add(dt)
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter

        da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From Patien_rocord where PID Like '%" & PIDfindTextBox.Text & "%'", con)
        da.Fill(dt)

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView

        con.Close()`

thank you so much for you help

Comment: That line I wrote `da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue...` is rather important; you should do it that way. See http://bobby-tables.com For a discussion into why. I'm also rather puzzled as to how, given that I gave you a complete and workable code that needed only very minor tweaks, you managed to add about another 5 lines that're unnecessary.You don't need to create a connection - dataadapter will do it. If you do create a connection you don't need to open and close it- dataadapter will do it. You don't need to add a datatable to a DataSet. DGV will use the defaultview automatically

Comment: All in, this would be preferable: `Dim da as New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Patien_roccord WHERE PID like ?", dbProvider & dbSource)` 
`da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", "%" & PIDfindTextBox.Text & "%")`
`Dim dt as New DataTable`
`da.Fill(dt)`
`PatienrocordBindingSource.DataSource = dt` `dataGridView1.DataSource = PatienrocordBindingSource` - less clutter, parameterized queries, keeping the bindingsource is useful for other things but not 100 necessary (can just set the DataSource of the grid to be dt)